# Two cards are chosen from a deck of 52 cards without replacement.

Tags: probability

Two cards are chosen from a deck of 52 cards without replacement.

Determine the probability that both cards are face cards or both cards are hearts?

I did face cards $\frac{12}{52} \times \frac{11}{51}$ + hearts $\frac{13}{52} \times \frac{12}{51}$

How do I solve for when both cards are face cards *and* hearts so I can subtract the overlap?

Answer (score 2):

The number of cards that are **Face cards AND Heart** are = 3
Hence Probability $$P={3\over52}.{2\over51}$$

Comment: how did you get 4? there are only 3 face cards that are hearts..

Answer (score 2):

For face cards that are hearts, there is only three such cards in the deck.

Therefore $P($heart face cards for two draws$)={3\over 52} \times {2\over 51}$.

Comment: oops I totally knew that.. :) thank you!